# The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0' is either not registered

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

We're trying to deploy our MVC solution to a customer, but they're getting an error while trying to log in.

I have searched for similar issues, but have not yet found a solution.

- It does have SQL CE 4.0 installed.
- I have checked app.config, but it seems fine. It has the lines as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19823037/2148311)

Could someone shed some light on the following error log?

> 2015-10-05 09:59:54,259 [  34] FATAL - [] Exception caught
>   System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   (0,0) : error 0175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.XDocumentExtensions.GetStorageMappingItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      at System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
>      at TWP.Areas.Core.Models.Authorization.DatabaseMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String userName, String password)
>      at TWP.Areas.Core.Models.Account.AccountProvider.Logon(TwpMembershipProvider membership, LogOnViewModel model)
>      at TWP.Areas.Core.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnViewModel model, String returnUrl)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    <section name="twpSettings" type="TWP.Areas.Core.Models.Settings.TwpSettingsSection, TWP"/>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <!-- Path to the configuration file for custom TWP settings -->
  <twpSettings configSource="Config\Twp.config"/>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Setting for increasing the max size of http requests -->
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000"/>
    <!-- Path to the configuration file for log4net -->
    <add key="log4net.Config" value="Config\log4net.config"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString1" connectionString="xxxxxx,OU=xxxxxx,DC=xxxxxx,DC=xxx"/>
    <add name="TWPConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!-- Default culture -->
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Core/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
        <add namespace="TWP.Areas.Core.Models"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- Clients -->
    <client>
        (removed)
    </client>
    <!-- Services -->
    <services>
        (removed)
    </services>
    <!-- Service Hosting Environment -->
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <!-- Bindings -->
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_DccWcfLibrary" closeTimeout="00:00:10" openTimeout="00:00:10" sendTimeout="00:00:10" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding_Large" maxReceivedMessageSize="1655360">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="163840" maxArrayLength="163840" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!-- Behaviors -->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="geocodingBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to check the web.config, not app.config - and suggest you share your web.config then

Comment: Thanks. Web.config is now added to the original post.

Comment: You need the config settings that the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact package addsin your web.config

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying SQL CE is missing in the web.config?

Shouldn't "providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"" work for SQL CE?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying - try to install that package in a new project, as check the web/app.config and System.Data.SqlClient is for SQL Server, not for SQL Compact, it needs: "System.Data.SqlServerCe"

Comment: You may be right, but it's only for this particular customer it's an issue. I'd expect this to be an issue in a dev environment as well, if the providerName was at fault. I have asked them to reinstall SQL CE 4.0 and see what happens. Uninstalling SQL CE on my dev machine reproduces the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what was wrong with SQL CE 4.0, but reinstalling it fixed the issue.