# SQL Server CE provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0' could not be loaded

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce-4

Good evening everyone. I try to use SQL Server Compact Edition and Entity Framework in simplest console application. But I get the following exception.

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact' registered in the application config
>   file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0' could not be loaded. Make sure that the
>   assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to
>   the running application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

So I started find the answer in the internet. After googling I found the following answers in StackOverflow:

[No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821284/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name)

I did the following configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLCE.DAL.BreakAwayContex" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=D:\TestDatabase.sdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

But I still have this exception. So how can I fix it? Thank you very much for answer or your device.

Have a nice evening.

Comment: Reinstall sql server compact 4...

Comment: Thank you for your response.I create a new test application and install EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact again.And everything is fine.Thank you.